# Can't store a video file in Internal Storage Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to download a video in internal storage in AsycTask. My code works fine. My log says the video is downloaded. But, I cant locate the folder nor file in my mobile phone.

Here is my code:

```
 String nameoffile = mInfo.getFilename() + "." + mInfo.getFileType();
File rootdirectory= cw.getFilesDir().getAbsoluteFile();

                       if (!rootdirectory.exists()) {
                        rootdirectory.mkdirs();
                   }

                    File file = new File(rootdirectory, nameoffile);
                    file.createNewFile();
                    Log.e("DEVICE", "file created");

                    Log.e("DEVICE", "" + nameoffile);

      InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

                    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                     long total = 0;
                    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                        total += count;
                        progress = (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile);
                        publishProgress(progress);
                        Log.e("PROGRESS", "" + mInfo.getFileType() + progress);
                        mInfo.setFilePercent(progress);
                       output.write(data, 0, count);
                       i = 1;

                    }
                    Log.e("Download Complete", "" + Mvalue);

                     // flushing output
                    output.flush();

                    // closing streams
                    output.close();
                    input.close();
                    Log.e("Download Complete", "" + 0);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I cant locate the folder nor file in my mobile phone

That is because you are downloading the video to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), which you have no access to, other than through your own app.

If you are expecting to see the video in some sort of file explorer, download the file to [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), making sure to [use `MediaScannerConnection` and `scanFile()`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2011/08/31/mtp-external-storage.html) so the video gets indexed.